# default consistency level and quorum setting in Cassandra and what is the best practice for tuning them

Tags: cassandra

I just started learning Cassandra, wondering if there is a default consistency level and quorum setting. seems to me there are quite a few parameters (like replicator number, quorum number) are tunable to balance Consistency with performance, is there a best practice on these settings? what's the default settings?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Default READ and WRITE consistency is ONE in cassandra.

Consistency can be specified for each query. `CONSISTENCY` command can be used from cqlsh to check current consistency value or set new consistency value.

Replication factor is number of copies of data required.

Deciding consistency depends on factors like whether it is write heavy workload or read heavy workload, how many nodes failure can be  handled at a time.

Ideally LOCAL_QUORUM READ & WRITE will give you strong consistency.

```
quorum = (sum_of_replication_factors / 2) + 1
```

For example, using a replication factor of 3, a quorum is 2 nodes ((3 / 2) + 1 = 2). The cluster can tolerate one replica down.Similar to QUORUM, the LOCAL_QUORUM level is calculated based on the replication factor of the same datacenter as the coordinator node. Even if the cluster has more than one datacenter, the quorum is calculated with only local replica nodes.

[Consistency in cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddac/doc/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntConfigConsistency.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The equation seems indicating quorum is determined by  replication_factor, why shall we config quorum again and wouldn't that create conflict?

Comment: yes quorum depends on replication factor... but while querying you have to specify consistency level... it can be quorum/one/local_quorum..etc

Comment: I don't see a CL needs to be specified in the query, here is an example: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryColumnsSort.html

Answer (score 0):

Following are the excellent links and should help you to understand consistency level and its configuration in Cassandra. Second link contains many pictorial diagrams.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html#dmlConfigConsistency__about-the-quorum-level

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsReadExp.html